# Volume down key not working. How to enter flashmode

Tags: flashtool

I am using Sony Xperia Z1 Compact. After replacing its screen the Volume-down key stopped working.

However I am in Bulgaria and cannot wait anymore for the Lollipop update, that is why I followed this guide:

http://techbeasts.com/2015/04/14/update-sony-xperia-z1-compact-d5503-to-android-502-lollipop-145a0242-firmware/

However without Volume-down key I cannot finish Step №9: For Xperia Z1 Compact Volume Down key will do the job of back key, just turn off your phone, keep the Volume Down key pressed and plug in the data cable.

Is there a way to simulate pressing the volume-down or to install the "FTF Firmeware" without it?
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to connect to your phone over a terminal and issue the following commands to reboot into Download Mode

```
su
reboot download
```

Your phone will need to be rooted to run the 'su' command.